# git diff --name-status : What does R100 mean?

Tags: git

When I do e.g. `git diff master --name-status` I see some lines with the `R100` prefix on them.

What does **`R100`** exactly mean?

---

I would assume  `R` means "moved". I am posting below [what I found in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), but nothing in this text says anything about `100` or numbers per se.

> `--name-status`
>   Show only names and status of changed files. See the description of the --diff-filter option on what the status letters mean.

and then

> `--diff-filter=[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)…​[*]]`
>   Select only files that are Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R), have their type (i.e. regular file, symlink, submodule, …​) changed (T), are Unmerged (U), are Unknown (X), or have had their pairing Broken (B). Any combination of the filter characters (including none) can be used. When * (All-or-none) is added to the combination, all paths are selected if there is any file that matches other criteria in the comparison; if there is no file that matches other criteria, nothing is selected.
>
> Also, these upper-case letters can be downcased to exclude. E.g. --diff-filter=ad excludes added and deleted paths.
>
> Note that not all diffs can feature all types. For instance, diffs from the index to the working tree can never have Added entries (because the set of paths included in the diff is limited by what is in the index). Similarly, copied and renamed entries cannot appear if detection for those types is disabled.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_changed_tracked_entries) for `git status` under "Changed Tracked Entries" appears to explain what `R100` means:

> `<X><score>`  The rename or copy score (denoting the percentage
> of similarity between the source and target of the
> move or copy). For example "R100" or "C75".

So, putting this together with what you cited above, the files you are seeing with `R100` status mean that they were moved, and that Git found a 100% match between that file and some other previously named file.

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803050/git-and-file-renaming-and-replacing) to a good @torek answer, which described the physics of how Git tracks content.

Comment: Thanks. i guess this is described under `git status`, but not actually under `diff` (although I guess of course `status` may call `diff` ..)